# AJAX not pulling or displaying the set of data from db

Tags: php, ajax

The AJAx script either not connecting to testData.php or its not able to pull in the data from the testData.php. Unable to isolate the problem, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have 2 files

- index.php - where AJAX script is and where I want the data displayed which is in the getdiv tag.
- textData.php - using mysql db to pull data. this script works and i copy/pasted the results at the bottom.

I believe the problem is somewhere in the AJAX script. its not pulling in the information if not its not able to display the information in the div tag.

testData.php - database script and results:

```
<?php
require_once('dbconv2.php');
$dbcon1 = Connection::getConnection();
    try {   $stmt = $dbcon1 ->query("SELECT 
                          click_count.page_ur, 
                          click_count.page_count
                     FROM click_count
                     ");                
                $testArray = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
                echo $row = $stmt->rowCount();              
            } 
            catch(PDOException $e) 
            {    echo $e->getMessage(); }   
var_dump($testArray); 

echo json_encode($testArray);
?>

array (size=7)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'page_ur' => string 'test record page1' (length=17)
      'page_count' => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'page_ur' => string 'test record page2' (length=17)
      'page_count' => string '4' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'page_ur' => string 'test record page3' (length=17)
      'page_count' => string '3' (length=1)

[{"page_ur":"test record page1","page_count":"1"},{"page_ur":"test record page2","page_count":"4"},{"page_ur":"test record page3","page_count":"3"},{"page_ur":"test record page5","page_count":"7"},{"page_ur":"test record page4","page_count":"9"},{"page_ur":"test record page6","page_count":"6"},{"page_ur":"test record page7","page_count":"2"}]
```

index.php - AJAX script

```
  <body>       
    <div id="getdiv"> </div>

     <div id="questionButton">
      <form method="POST" name="form_questions" action="">         
        <BUTTON class="btn_get" id ="btn_get" NAME="btn_get">getInfo</BUTTON>        
      </form>
    </div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>       
      $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#btn_get').on('click', function(e) { 
          $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false, 
            url: 'testData.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(info){  
             $("#getdiv").html(info[0].page_ur);
             }
          });
          e.preventDefault();
          });         
      });                  
    </script> 
  </body>
```

Comment: what does the var_dump(testarray) give you?

Comment: If that var_dump is in your "faulty" code and not just for debugging the problem,t hen you'll have to remove that. the var_dump output will also be seen by the JS code and be considered corrupt+invalid json data. If it is just for debugging, then do a `console.log(info)` in your JS `success` handler and see what's actually getting through to your client-side code.

Comment: hello,I tried your suggestion and still not working. the results of var_dump was posted part of by post above.. i also added console.log(info); with no success.. any other ideas???